# UNIX clear command after program run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm having problem with inserting command '**clear**' in bash script
what I want is to clear the screen

```
printMenu
until [ $choice -eq 4 ]; do


done
```

Comment: I presume there's a `case` to match your `esac`. But *why* do you want to clear the screen? As a user, I hate programs that clear the screen; I likely had information there, and I can clear it myself easily enough.

Comment: yes you are right but sometime the user want that action to be done

Comment: Of course -- that's why the `clear` command exists. But please consider whether clearing the screen (and thereby destroying information owned by the user) is really a requirement for your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function printMenu {
    clear
    ...

done
clear
```